# Python 3.6 - Crear mi propia clase en Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, clase, ventana

tengo una aplicación desarrollada en Tkinter y me gustaría crear una clase para obtener cada vez que necesite una ventana de tamaño fijo con un cuadro de texto y un botón. Pero no se como hacerlo.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Entry, Button, Label

class Ventana():
    def __init__(self, x, y, ancho, alto, titulo, texto):
        self.ventana = Tk()
        self.ventana.geometry(str(ancho)+ "x" + str(alto) + "+" + str(x) + "+" + str(y))
        self.ventana.title(str(titulo))

        Label(self.ventana, text="Escriba algo:").place(x=5, y=0)
        self.txt_texto = Entry(self.ventana).place(x=5, y=25, width=185)
        self.btn_boton = Button(self.ventana, text="Miau").place(x=5, y=50, width=185)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    v1 = Ventana(450, 300, 200, 90, "#", "Buenos días")
    v2 = Ventana(750, 300, 200, 90, "&", "Buenas noches")
```

Answer (score 0):

la forma que yo lo haria seria primero crear un archivo nuevo, que servira como mi modulo para crear mis ventanas personalizadas y luego incluirlas en cada archivo que necesite.
Por ejemplo, si crea el archivo misventanas.py
Luego lo incluye como un modulo
from misventanas import *

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/395416)

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).